# Integrate a complex exponential

Tags: integration, complex-numbers, exponential-function

I am trying to calculate this expression:

$\int dp \ \exp(-Aip^2+iBp)$

where A and B are real. I integrate p over the reals from -infinity to infinity. How can I visualize this expression and will it yield a sensible result?

Comment: This looks like a Gaussian - so no elementary antiderivative. But if you mean to integrate on all of $\mathbb{R}$ you can complete the square.

Comment: In total generality this is provably not integrable to any "good" closed form. If you have a particular **definite** integral in mind then maybe we can do something, see the "Gaussian integral". You should be able to write this in terms of that normal cdf $\Psi$ function though

Comment: It seems you're asking about the Fourier transform $$\mathcal{F}_p\left[e^{-i A p^2}\right](B)=\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{- i A p^2}\, e^{i B p} \, dp=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{\sqrt{i A}}\, e^{\frac{i B^2}{4 A}}\tag{1}$$ which is valid for $\Im(A)<0$. Mathematica gives the result $$\int e^{-i A p^2}\, e^{i B p} \, dp=\frac{(-1)^{3/4} \sqrt{\pi} e^{\frac{i B^2}{4 A}} \text{erf}\left(\frac{\sqrt[4]{-1} (B-2 A p)}{2 \sqrt{A}}\right)}{2 \sqrt{A}}\tag{2}$$ for the indefinite integral.